# Is the total current of a solar cell the sum of the busbars?

Tags: solar-cell

I have many 5x5 inch solar cells with two busbars  which I've attached tabbing wires to. This is my first attempt which is pretty poor I know (flux everywhere etc.)

I'm measuring the short current from each tabbing wire against the back of the plate, and I'm getting 100mA for each tabbing wire. I tried measuring from both tabbing wires at the same time and got the exact same figure. I measured directly from the printed busbars and also got the same figure for each one. Am I doing something incorrectly? Is the total current of the solar cell the sum of both busbars? If not what is the purpose of having two? The entire of the back plate is positive.

Can't I just attach one tabbing wire right at the end of the solar cell if I am getting the same current reading from probing directly onto the printed busbars?

[image]

Comment: Are they connected on board? Then OK

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the finer collection wires go across the entire width of the cell with no break in the middle.  Electrically, the busbars are identical, i.e. the current from one measured alone does not add with the current from the other.  They may have included two for redundancy, to minimize the amount of power lost in the resistance of the fine wires, or for a reason specific to its intended purpose if the cell was salvaged (possibly to carry the current of a large number of cells in parallel when installed in an array).  You can just use one of the busbars, Isc of 100mA isn't huge so you're probably not losing a lot of power in the I2R losses of another inch or two of current path.

Comment: That answers it, thanks. An additional question, can I just attach the tabbing wire to the end of the printed busbars. I see numerous tutorials where people will lay tabbing over the printed busbars. Is this unnecessary?

Comment: It might give a slight benefit to have the tabbing wire go all the way across; the resistance of the printed wires is higher than normal wire, but it wouldn't be very noticeable.  There's also the possibility of damaging the cell trying to tack unnecessary wire onto the printed busbar.